# Google Maps API Info Window Does Not Scroll Vertically on iOS 12

Tags: javascript, ios, css, google-maps, overflow

In the documentation for Google Maps JavaScript API, there is an [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple) of how to add an info window to a marker.

When rendered, it appears google adds `overflow:auto` to the info window container, which is great! In Chrome's developer tools, I can simulate viewing the page from a iOS device and I'm able to scroll vertically in the info window. However, when I view this page from an actual iOS device I'm unable to scroll vertically.

Below is a snippet of the related code.

```js
// This example displays a marker at the center of Australia.
// When the user clicks the marker, an info window opens.

function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });

  var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
      'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
      'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
      'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
      '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
      'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
      'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
      'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
      'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
      'Heritage Site.</p>'+
      '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
      'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
      '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
</script>
```

[image: Info Window]

I've read a few SO questions that seem to be related:

- [overflow:auto not working in touch devices(iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438690/overflowauto-not-working-in-touch-devicesios)
- [Vertical scroll not working on Mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33441111/vertical-scroll-not-working-on-mobile-safari)

But these solutions haven't resolved my problem. How can I make this content scrollable on iOS 12 and up?

*Update*: It seems this might be an issue specifically with iOS 12. An iOS 11 device (iPhone 6s plus) was able to scroll vertically. All other (five) devices that have had an issue scrolling vertically are iOS 12 and up.

Comment: Hi have you got any solution for this?
if got then please provide it so that it will help some one.

Comment: @Rits unfortunately, no. I was able to work around it by adjusting the line-height and font-size of the content in the info window with a media query. I wasn’t able to find a solution to the actual problem.

Comment: :( ohh, my bad luck. any way thanks for reply.